# Find location of Golang application

Tags: go

I have a Golang application which is being deployed into a container via Kubernetes. Within the service I would like to read a file which is nested within the application.

I'm struggling to find out how to set the current working directory to the location of the application.

Currently the application panics with an error due to the relative paths not being aligned:

```
open /workspace/source/package/file.csv: no such file or directory
```

I've tried using the following code and appending the file name:

```
var (
_, b, _, _ = runtime.Caller(0)
basepath   = filepath.Dir(b)
)
```

However this still doesn't work. Is there a way to find the applications current location and then append the filename?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Just don't hard-code paths in your application. Take paths, along with other configuration, by CLI parameter, environment variable, or config file.

Comment: I'm not hard coding the paths. Can you provide examples of the CLI parameters etc.? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use [os.Executable](https://godoc.org/os#Executable) to find the path to the executable.

```
b, err := os.Executable()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
basepath := filepath.Dir(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just `cd` before executing the application? Then you can use relative paths.